# What's the usecase of gcc's used attribute?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, icc

```
#include <stdio.h>

// xyz will be emitted with -flto (or if it is static) even when
// the function is unused

__attribute__((__used__))
void xyz() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

What do I need this for?

Is there any way I could still reach `xyz` somehow besides directly calling the function, like some `dlsym()` like magic?

Comment: Is `dlsym` not the answer you're looking for? It's confusing to mention the answer like that, right in the question.

Comment: I suppose you could have calls to `xyz` hidden in inline asm that the compiler doesn't know about.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No, it is not. `dlsym()` doesn't work for executables, that's why I wrote "like some".

Comment: @Thomas I'm pretty sure an executable can `dlopen` itself.

Comment: @melpomene: I tried it, but the symbol isn't found.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Attribute `used` is helpful in situation when you want to force compiler to emit symbol, when normally it may be omitted. As [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) says (emphasis mine):

> This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be
>   emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is not
>   referenced. This is useful, **for example, when the function is
>   referenced only in inline assembly**.

For instance, if you have code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

static int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
   int result = 0;

   // some inline assembly that calls foo and updates result

   std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

you might notice, that no symbol `foo` is present with `-O` flag (optimization level `-O1`):

```
g++ -O -pedantic -Wall check.cpp -c
check.cpp:3: warning: ‘int foo(int, int)’ defined but not used
nm check.o | c++filt | grep foo
```

As a result you cannot reference `foo` within this (imaginary) inline assembly.

By adding:

```
__attribute__((__used__))
```

it turns into:

```
g++ -O -pedantic -Wall check.cpp -c
nm check.o | c++filt | grep foo
00000000 t foo(int, int)
```

thus now `foo` can be referenced within it.

You may also have spotted that `gcc`'s warning is now gone, as you have tell you compiler that you are sure that `foo` is actually used "behind the scene".

Comment: Another use case, especially in C++, is for debugging helpers. For instance, you might have a `void dump()` method which pretty-prints an internal object. You won't call it anywhere in your program, but you want to be able to call it when you're paused in the debugger. `__attribute__((used))` will ensure that it isn't eliminated as dead code.

Comment: @BeccaRoyal-Gordon If your debugger is GDB, the preferred way to do it today is writing a [pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.pdf) (page 438), since doing so through python will work automagically when you use `print <object>`

Answer (score 3):

A particular usecase is for interrupt service routines in a static library.
For example, a timer overflow interrupt:

`void __attribute__((interrupt(TIMERA_VECTOR),used)) timera_isr(void)`

This timera_isr is never called by any function in the user code, but it might form an essential part of a library. 
To ensure it is linked and there isn't a interrupt vector pointing to an empty section the keyword ensures the linker doesn't optimise it out.

Comment: I don't think that's true. ISR functions are referenced the moment you take their address to put into the interrupt vector table. That may happen indirectly (e.g. using a complier-specific syntax such as `__attribute__((interrupt(X)))`) but there's no need to add `__attribute__((__used__))` to that.

Comment: When the static library is assembIed don't think the vector table is filled, that happens when the library is linked in the final program. Since program doesn't use the function in the library I don't think it will get added to the vector table otherwise.

Comment: When the static library is assembled, none of its exported functions are used at all, that happens when you link the library to the final program. The assembler (or the compiler) doesn't throw any of the unused functions away, that's the job of the linker.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a global variable or function that is unused, gcc will optimized it out (with warning), but if you declared the global variable or the function with `'__attribute__((used))'`, gcc will include it in object file (and linked executable).

https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2013-09/msg00108.html

Answer (score 0):

Another use case is to generate proper coverage information for header files. Functions declared in header files are usually removed by the compiler when unreferenced. Therefore, you will get 100% coverage in your coverage reports even if you forgot to call some functions that are located in the header file. To prevent this, you may mark your function with `__attribute__((used))` in your coverage builds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to previous answers:

All the `used` attribute does is make sure the compiler emits the decorated function - it still might be discarded by the linker, if it was invoked with gc switches.

To make sure the function is alive in the final binary you'd want to add the `retain` attribute (at least for ELF binaries): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-retain-function-attribute